# How to limit diff to just added lines?

Tags: git, diff

I would like to display the lines added by a given commit and *only* that.

Using `git show` I have managed to remove the metadata with `--format=""` and the contextual diff lines with `-U0`. e.g.,

```
git show -U0 --format="" 8d7d85c99 -- XXXX
```

```
diff --git a/XXXX b/XXXX
index 9005466e8..d519c27fb 100644
--- a/XXXX
+++ b/XXXX
@@ -5 +5 @@
-  "version": "8",
+  "version": "9",
@@ -62 +62 @@
-    "version": "6",
+    "version": "7",
```

Ideally I'd like the output to show the added lines *only*. e.g.,

```
+  "version": "9",
+    "version": "7",
```

I know I can achieve this with things like `awk` or `sed` but I'm interested in knowing whether it's possible to do this using `git` only.

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot pipe the output to another command? Would be possible to create an alias comment in git for this?